# Search if a specific attribute in all the elements of an array match a condition

Tags: arrays, testing, swift, element, conditional-statements

I'm working with Swift, SpriteKit and Xcode 6,

I have an array of a SKSpriteNode class :

```
class EnemyVehicle: SKSpriteNode {
}

var vehicles = [EnemyVehicle]()
```

So I can add elements to this array like this:

```
vehicles.append(EnemyVehicle(imageNamed:"mySprite"))
```

And the superclass SKSpriteNode contains an attribute which is position.y, and I can access it in every element of my array with `vehicle[x].position.y`.

My question is: is it possible to test every specific attribute in an array (here position.y) and watch if it match the conditions? For example, if I want a condition which is true only when all of the position.y values of all my elements in my array are superior than 0? I know I could do it with a loop, but is there another easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want reduce.

Reduce takes a starting value, and then a closure that takes the running value and the next element of the array, and combines these two elements together, carrying that result forward to combine with the next element.

For example:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
// starting with zero, add each element to a total
let sum = a.reduce(0) { total, i in total + i }
// sum = 6
```

To check if all elements in an array match a given criteria, you want a combining function that checks the property and returns true or false, anding that with the previous criteria:

```
// assuming you’re ok for true for an empty array:
let allAboveGround = vehicles.reduce(true) {
  previous, vehicle in
    previous && vehicle.position.y > 0
}
```

There’s one downside to this – as soon as you hit a value that is false, you could stop right there because the overall value cannot be true.  Reduce doesn’t cater for this so you may want to write a loop, or maybe an `all` function that wraps a loop, that quits early under these conditions:

```
func all<S: SequenceType>(source: S, pred: S.Generator.Element->Bool) -> Bool {
    for x in source {
        if !pred(x) { return false }
    }
    return true
}

let allAboveGround = all(vehicles) { $0.position.y > 0 }
```